# Issue with AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I've just implemented an `AlertDialog` into a fragment within my Android app and it is causing my application to crash when it is shown.

Any ideas on why this might be?

**Dialog**

```
void addSiteOption() {

    String[] options = {"Auto", "Manual"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("Add");
    builder.setMessage("Auto add - download. \n Manually add - no internet connection.");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectionIndex) {

            switch (selectionIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    break;

                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Comment: can you post your complete log here? But I believe the issue is in this line:
`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`
Try right `getActivity()` only.

Comment: Ahh see I did think it might be Context related. I'll try getActivity

Comment: Yeah that did it! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `Application context` here but you need to get the calling `activity's context`.So change your code

From this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

To this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Context=container.getContext();

private void showAlert() {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to clear  history?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("sure", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
```